# How to add many events to Google Calendar - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-calendar-api

I have an application where I am creating a Google Calendar and am adding a lot of events to it, all at once. It seems that the Google Calendar API doesn't allow me to add events to the calendar locally and then insert the calendar with a request, or add multiple events with a single request. So I have to usually make 40 requests in a loop to add all my events, which usually results in me getting a response of "rate limit exceeded"...

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an answer from a quite similar post about [Insert multiple calendar.events in google calendar(API)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50471476/15384825), it is advised to use the [Batch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch) method to be able to add multiple events at once. However, I'm no expert on Swift nor knowledgeable enough on how to implement Batch method in Swift programming, but you can refer to the article.

Additionally, when you encounter a [403: Rate Limit Exceeded](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_rate_limit_exceeded) error, it is suggested to use the [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#exponential-backoff) method. Alternatively, you may also check [Resolve a 403 error: Daily limit exceeded](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_daily_limit_exceeded).